# AWK get string and quoted string

Tags: awk

I have a log file containing something like this

```
Mar 19 07:00:32 192.168.100.58 DefensePro: 21-11-2010 09:31:18 WARNING 150 HttpFlood "HTTP Page Flood Attack" TCP 0.0.0.0 0 192.168.100.6 0 0 Regular "File Server" term 0 0 N/A 0 N/A medium forward XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-18CE-2222B3148BBC
```

How can I get specific string (using awk or nawk) , to become like this :

```
Mar 19 07:00:32,192.168.100.58,HTTP Page Flood Attack,192.168.100.6,medium
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post more data from the logfile?

Comment: `awk` splits the input data on spaces (by default). You intend to create a comma separated output which could be achieved by setting the `OFS` variable. 

Since your log has no delimiter you will have to identify which fields you want to capture. However, this is a fragile approach since it would break if your log has additional data on different lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
awk '{j = 0;for(i=1;i<NF;i++){if(i == 11 && index($i,"\"") > 0){printf(",%s",$i);i++;while(index($i,"\"") == 0){printf(" %s",$i);i++;}printf(" %s",$i);j=i;}else if(i < 5 || i == (j+4) || i == (NF - 2)){printf(",%s",$i);}}}'
```

Logic is i print the fields till 5 and from field 11 where the " starts i print the fields till the next " comes. I store the position where we get the last " as j. Then i print the field j + 4 and the last but 2nd field

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F\" '{
    split($1,a,/ /)
    split($3,b,/ /)
    split($5,c,/ /)
    printf "%s %s %s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],$2,b[5],c[8]
}' file
Mar 19 07:00:32,192.168.100.58,HTTP Page Flood Attack,192.168.100.6,medium
```